# Ошибка в двумерном массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

Создается двумерный массив, который заполняется знаком `-`, а при `i == 2`, строка должна заполниться знаком `+`, но этого не происходит. Почему?

```
var rowArr = [], arr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            rowArr[j] = '-';
            if(i == 2)
                rowArr[j] = "+";
        }
        arr[i] = rowArr;
    }
    console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал вариант, который вы описали в комментариях, думаю это то, что вам нужно:

```js
var arr = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        if (arr[j] == undefined) arr[j] = [];
        arr[j][i] = (i == 2) ? '+' : '-';
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо, а не могли бы объяснить почему мой вариант не работал?

Comment: @xfranklin, `i[q]` вы заполняли знаком `-`, а нужно было заполнять `i[k]`

Comment: @xfranklin, совсем затупил, тут можно обойтись одним циклом, без цикла `for(var q = 0; q < 5; q++)`

Comment: Спасибо а можно в js приваивать массив вот так `array[i][j] = elem` ?

Comment: @xfranklin, все верно